# Nginx configure folder for subdomains

Tags: nginx, configuration, virtualhost

How I configure a single folder with name "projects", where each subfolder is a subdomain?
Example:
I have site `example.com`
On my server I have folder

```
/var/www/html/example.com
```

I created new folder:

```
/var/www/html/projects/
```

And every folder in 'projects' directory is new subdomain:

```
/var/www/html/projects/site1 = site1.exapmle.com
```

Thanks

---

@richard-smith, I set config file `projects` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` with content:

```
server {
listen 80;

root   /var/www/html/projects/$domain;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>\.example\.com)$;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}
//instead example.com my domen name.

Created symbol link in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and run `service nginx reload`.
But after open `site1.example.com`. I get `"This site can’t be reached"`. But my `example.com` work fine.

Comment: check your server logs first, may be any fcgi problem

Comment: Have you set up DNS for the `site1` subdomain?

Comment: **Always** check with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se). Browsers are far too "user friendly" (read: not accurate enough for diagnostics).

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression in the server_name directive will allow you to capture the name of the subdomain and use it in the `root` directive.

```
server {
    server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>\.example\.com)$;
    root   /var/www/html/projects/$domain;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for more.

Comment: Thanks! I added new info to my question after testing. Please, see it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to match subdomains *excluding* 'www', with folder names being just the subdomain name, and this syntax worked for me.

```
server {
    ...
    server_name ~^(?!www)(?P<domain>.+)\.example\.com$;
    root /var/www/html/projects/$domain;
    ...
}
```

Where `test.example.com` will use root location `/var/www/html/projects/test`